# Postman collection parser which injects collection to Jira/xray addon

Tags: python, parsing, json

I'we created an interface that communicates with Postman collection and Jira api more precise the Xray addon for jira.
I would much appreciate if you could give me notes on how to improve this code.

- Adding variables in constructor, too loosely maybe.
- Function **add_steps_to_test_case_v1** and **add_steps_to_test_case_v2** could they be merged into one?
- Use just module instead of class?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from jiraapi import *
import json
import sys
import re


class PostmanToXray(object):
    """ PostmanToXray""" 
    def __init__(self, postman_collection):
        """ Constructor creates a connection object to jira/xray api
            and parses collection.json file
        """
        self.jira_obj = self._connect_to_api()
        self.parsed_json = self.parse_json_file(postman_collection)
        self.collection_version = self.collection_format()
        self.jira_testexecution_id = ""
        self.jira_project_name = ""

    def _connect_to_api(self):
        """ Connects to jira api """
        try:
            client = JiraAPI()
        except Exception, e:
            print e

        return client

    def parse_json_file(self, postman_collection):
        """ Uses json third party module to parse postman collections """
        with open(postman_collection) as data_file:    
            json_data = json.load(data_file)

        return json_data

    def jira_issue_correct_format(self, testexecution_id):
        """ Checks if provided testexecutionId is on the correct format
            Jira/Xray/Test Execution
            input_param:  testexecution_id
            output_param: True/False
        """
        try:
            self.jira_obj.send_get('xray', 'testexec/%s/test' % testexecution_id)
        except Exception, e:
            print "jira issue '%s' is not on Xray/test execution format" % testexecution_id
            return

        self.jira_testexecution_id = testexecution_id
        self.jira_project_name = testexecution_id.split('-')[0]

        return True

    def collection_format(self):
        """ Two standards currently exists for postman collections,
            we have to differentiate between them, as v1 or v2
            'folders' is V1 specific and 'item' is V2 specific
        """
        try:
            self.parsed_json["info"]
        except KeyError, e:
            print "Postman Collection V1"
            return "folders"

        print "Postman Collection V2"
        return "item"

    def import_postman_collection(self):
        """ Checks if test exectuion run in jira has any test cases assocciated with it.
            If none, we create all new test cases and append them to the test execution run.
            If test exectuion run has one or more tests assocciated with it, we do
            removal of test cases that are in xray but not the the Postman collection,
            update on existing test cases,
            adding of tests cases that are only in the collection but not in jira
        """
        testexecution_obj = self.jira_obj.send_get('xray', 'testexec/%s/test' % self.jira_testexecution_id)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        if testexecution_obj['iTotalRecords'] > 0:
            print "Test execution run has tests, updating process..."
            # gather test cases in Xray in existing test case map
            existing_test_case_map = {}
            for test_case in testexecution_obj["entries"]:
                existing_test_case_map[test_case["key"]] = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?<=">)(.*)(?=</a>)', test_case["userColumns"]["summary"]))

            # start with removing test cases that are only in Xray
            self.remove_test_case(existing_test_case_map)

            # loop through collection and do update and add tests
            for item in self.parsed_json[self.collection_version]: # collection.json
                only_in_collection = True
                for key, value in existing_test_case_map.items(): # jira/xray/test
                    if item["name"] == value: # test case exists in jira has the same name, update it
                        only_in_collection = False
                        print "test exists with same name in both xray and collection '%s', xrayId '%s':update!" % (value, key)
                        self.update_test_case(key, item) # list of steps_ids
                        continue

                if only_in_collection: # add test case to xray and testexecution run
                    print "test case only in collection, create new test case"
                    new_testcase_id = self.create_test_case(item)
                    arguments = {
                        "keys":[str(new_testcase_id)]
                    }
                    try:
                        # appending test case to test execution run
                        self.jira_obj.send_post('xray', 'testexec/%s/test' % self.jira_testexecution_id, arguments)
                    except Exception, e:
                        print e
                        sys.exit(1)

        else:
            print "Adding test cases to an empty xray test execution object"
            # loop through collection and add tests
            for item in self.parsed_json[self.collection_version]: # collection.json
                new_testcase_id = self.create_test_case(item)
                arguments = {
                    "keys":[str(new_testcase_id)]
                }
                try:
                    # appending test case to test execution run
                    self.jira_obj.send_post('xray', 'testexec/%s/test' % self.jira_testexecution_id, arguments)
                except Exception, e:
                    print e
                    sys.exit(1)

    def remove_test_case(self, existing_test_case_map):
        """ Takes in a map of existing test cases in xray mapped with there name
            If test only exists in xray and not in the collection, it will be removed
                from the test execution run.
            NB: Test case still exists in jira, it's just not longer associated
            with corresponding test exectuion run.
        """
        # first ckeck if we have test cases only in xray, then remove it
        for key, value in existing_test_case_map.items(): # jira/xray/test
            only_in_xray = True
            for coll_item in self.parsed_json[self.collection_version]: # collection.json
                if coll_item["name"] == value: # both in collection and xray
                    only_in_xray = False
                    break

            if only_in_xray:
                print "Removing test case with id: %s from test execution run" % key
                try:
                    self.jira_obj.send_delete('xray', 'testexec/%s/test/?testKeys=%s' % (self.jira_testexecution_id, key))
                except Exception, e:
                    print e
                    sys.exit(1)

    def update_test_case(self, testcase_id, collection_item):
        """ Update an existing test case, that alrady exits in under the same name in collection
            and Xray, using collection as the master.
            First all existing steps in test case are removed, then steps are insterted again using
            collecion as master.
            input_parm: testcase_id, collection_item
        """
        testcase_steps = self.jira_obj.send_get('xray', 'test/%s/steps' % testcase_id)

        # start with removing all existing steps from test case
        for step in testcase_steps:
            testcase_steps = self.jira_obj.send_delete('xray', 'test/%s/steps/%s' % (testcase_id, str(step["id"])))

        # add steps to test case
        if self.collection_version == "folders":
            self.add_steps_to_test_case_v1(testcase_id, collection_item)
        else:
            self.add_steps_to_test_case_v2(testcase_id, collection_item)

    def add_steps_to_test_case_v1(self, testcase_id, folder):
        """ Adds steps to a test case, uses regex to extract all tests
            associated with each test in postman collection.
        """
        # loop through collection -> order, each order represents one step in xray
        for order in folder["order"]:
            for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]:
                if order == test_case["id"]:
                    expected_result_list = re.findall(r'(?<=tests\[")(.*)(?::|"\])', test_case["tests"])
                    expected_result_set = list(set(expected_result_list))
                    expected_result_str = '\n'.join(expected_result_set)

                    manual_steps = {"step": test_case["name"], "data": expected_result_str, "result": ""}
                    # inserts steps to newly created xray tests by calling xray api
                    try:
                        self.jira_obj.send_post('xray', 'test/%s/steps' % testcase_id, manual_steps)
                    except Exception, e:
                        print e
                        sys.exit(1)

        return True

    def add_steps_to_test_case_v2(self, testcase_id, collection_item):
        """ Adds steps to a test case, uses regex to extract all tests
            associated with each test in postman collection.
        """
        # loop through collection -> order, each order represents one step in xray
        for item in collection_item["item"]:
            for event in item["event"]:
                expected_result_list = re.findall(r'(?<=tests\[")(.*)(?::|"\])', event["script"]["exec"])
                expected_result_set = list(set(expected_result_list))
                expected_result_str = '\n'.join(expected_result_set)

                manual_steps = {"step": item["name"], "data": expected_result_str, "result": ""}
                # inserts steps to newly created xray tests by calling xray api
            try:
                self.jira_obj.send_post('xray', 'test/%s/steps' % testcase_id, manual_steps)
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                sys.exit(1)

        return True

    def create_test_case(self, collection_item):
        """ Creates a new test case and append it to tests in test execution run 
            input_param: collection_item
            output_parm: newly created test case
        """
        arguments = {
            "fields": {
                "project": { "key": self.jira_project_name },
                "summary": str(collection_item["name"]),
                "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
                "issuetype": {
                    "name": "Test" 
                },
                "customfield_11740": {
                    "value": "Manual"
                }
            }
        }

        try:
            # creates test case
            new_testcase = self.jira_obj.send_post('jira', 'issue/', arguments)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            sys.exit(1)
        print "new test caseid: %s with name: %s" % (new_testcase["key"], collection_item["name"])

        # add steps to test case
        if self.collection_version == "folders":
            self.add_steps_to_test_case_v1(new_testcase["key"], collection_item)
        else:
            self.add_steps_to_test_case_v2(new_testcase["key"], collection_item)

        return new_testcase["key"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "too few arguments or too many!"
        print "Input has too be on this format."
        print "$ python postmantoxray.py postman_collection and 'jira test execution issue id'"
    else:
        ptx = PostmanToXray(sys.argv[1])
        # check if jira issue is Xray test execution issue, otherwise reject
        if ptx.jira_issue_correct_format(sys.argv[2]):
            ptx.import_postman_collection()
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions:

In `_connect_to_api()`, if the client is not created successfully, the constructor continues to execute. Which will lead to other errors later on. If the only thing you can do with an exception is print it's message to the user, you likely should not be handling the exception at all. Handle the exception when you can make a meaningful decision.

`import_postman_collection()` and others uses `sys.exit()` to handle an exception. This is bad because it dictates how `PostmanToXray` can be used. Maybe I would like to use it as part of a long running service. However, if this part of code executes, everything stops. At it's core, this is the same issue as the previous paragraph, except here you go the other direction and stop execution instead of logging a message and continuing.

I don't know `jiraapi`, but I suspect would hope you can catch a more specifically typed exception than the base `Exception` class. I'd also would not be surprised if functions like `send_get()` can raise exceptions. If they do, these are not being handled.

---

Returning values:

`_connect_to_api()` and `parse_json_file()` assign a value to a variable, then return that value without interacting with it in any way. They both can be changed to return the result directly instead of creating an temporary variable. This would have an added benefit in `_connect_to_api()`. It makes it clear what is returned when the exception is raised.

`jira_issue_correct_format()` explicitly returns `True` on success, but implicitly returns `None` when an exception occurs. This behavior does not match what the docstring says. It is better to be consistent and always explicitly return a boolean.

---

Code repetition:

`add_steps_to_test_case_v1()` and `add_steps_to_test_case_v2()` only differ in how the payload is constructed. Have those steps the specific parts, then use a single method to send the request.

Example:

```
def unique_tests(test_names):
    matches = re.findall(r'(?<=tests\[")(.*)(?::|"\])', test_names)
    return '\n'.join(set(matches))

def send_steps(self, testcase_id, step_name, data):
    manual_steps = {"step": step_name, "data": data, "result": ""}
    # inserts steps to newly created xray tests by calling xray api
    try:
        self.jira_obj.send_post('xray', 'test/%s/steps' % testcase_id, manual_steps)
    except Exception, e:
        # Better exception handling. Maybe let exception propagate up

def add_steps_to_test_case_v1(self, testcase_id, folder):
    for order in folder["order"]:
        for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]:
            if order == test_case["id"]:
                self.send_steps(testcase_id, test_case["name"],
                                unique_tests(test_case["tests"]))

def add_steps_to_test_case_v2(self, testcase_id, folder):
    for item in collection_item["item"]:
        for event in item["event"]:
            self.send_steps(testcase_id, item["name"],
                            unique_tests(event["script"]["exec"]))
```

---

Smaller Comments:

`import_postman_collection()` is over 50 lines long and has 5 levels of nesting at one point. Both of these are an indication that you might want to break it up into smaller sub-methods. By adding named sub-methods, you can remove some of the comments that simply state what the following block of code do. In general, it is better to have comments say **why** something is happening or being done, rather than **what** is being done.

The docstrings generally only describe what the methods are doing, but don't document what the arguments are expected to be. Simply listing their names is not helpful as that can be seen in the signature. The docstring should give meaning to the contents of the parameters.

`str.join()` can take any iterable, so you don't need to convert the set back to a list.

There are multiple methods that don't refer to `self`. These can be changed to `@staticmethod`s.

Remove the pdb break point.

Comment: 1 `_connect_to_api()`: I have error handling in jiraapi, and it breaks out if it fails, is then no try-catch block needed in this function?  2 `_connect_to_api()`: should just do return JiraAPI and return json.load(data_file)?  
3 `jira_issue_correct_format`: Forgot the return False, thanks  
4 `import_postman_collection()`: This function needs to broken up, the outer most if-else is easily done, but more should be done, any suggestions?  
5`@staticmethod`: Should I maybe preferably use does python module approach instead of python class approach?  

Thanks allot for your input!

Comment: Code repetition: At closer look there are minor differences between the two functions `add_steps_to_test_case_v1()` and `add_steps_to_test_case_v2()``if order == test_case["id"]` and  work on different objects from the collection, how can this be achieved in one function?
Once again, really appreciated your feedback

Comment: 1) If `JiraAPI()` can throw an exception, it should me handled. What I'm saying is that you are handling it in the wrong place. Your main block would likely be the correct place. 2) Yes. 4) The block executed by `if only_in_collection:` seems like a good candidate. 5) Using a class is fine. This is more of a personal preference thing, than a right and wrong thing. 6) See update in answer for example of eliminating the code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

This is my improved version of `import_postman_collection()` added a simple bool var and was able to take out the `else` part.

```
def import_postman_collection(self):
    """ Checks if test exectuion run in jira has any test cases assocciated with it.
        If none, we create all new test cases and append them to the test execution run.
        If test exectuion run has one or more tests assocciated with it, we do
        removal of test cases that are in xray but not the the Postman collection,
        update on existing test cases,
        adding of tests cases that are only in the collection but not in jira
    """
    testexecution_obj = self.jira_obj.send_get('xray', 'testexec/%s/test' % self.jira_testexecution_id)

    testexecution_with_tests = True if testexecution_obj['iTotalRecords'] > 0 else False

    print "Test execution run has tests, updating process..."
    # gather test cases in Xray in existing test case map
    if testexecution_with_tests:
        existing_test_case_map = {}
        for test_case in testexecution_obj["entries"]:
            existing_test_case_map[test_case["key"]] = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?<=">)(.*)(?=</a>)', test_case["userColumns"]["summary"]))

        # start with removing test cases that are only in Xray
        self.remove_test_case(existing_test_case_map)

    # loop through collection and do update and add tests
    for item in self.parsed_json[self.collection_version]: # collection.json
        only_in_collection = True
        if testexecution_with_tests:
            for key, value in existing_test_case_map.items(): # jira/xray/test
                if item["name"] == value: # test case exists in jira has the same name, update it
                    only_in_collection = False
                    print "test exists with same name in both xray and collection '%s', xrayId '%s':update!" % (value, key)
                    self.update_test_case(key, item) # list of steps_ids
                    continue

        if only_in_collection: # add test case to xray and testexecution 
            new_testcase_id = self.create_test_case(item)
            arguments = {
                "keys":[str(new_testcase_id)]
            }
            try:
                # appending test case to test execution run
                self.jira_obj.send_post('xray', 'testexec/%s/test' % self.jira_testexecution_id, arguments)
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                sys.exit(1)
```